# TypeScript: How can I declare a type for a JavaScript array with different element types but not a fixed length?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I will have a JavaScript array that has a specific pattern of different element types at the start, but then a (pattern of) repeating item type(s) at the end, to an arbitrary number of repetitions.

How can I declare a TypeScript type that will be compatible with this JavaScript array?

```
interface A {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
}

interface B {
  baz: Baz
}

interface Bat {
  // getArr(): [A, B, B, B],  // tuple type puts types at specific indexes 
                              // but only supports a fixed number of elements
  // getArr(): Array<A | B>,  // array type notation allows arbitrary number 
                              // of elements but doesn't require them to be
                              // in specific positions
}
```

**Edit:**

To clarify further, I am experimenting with using external TypeScript declarations with vanilla JavaScript code to identify issues in existing JavaScript code.  I understand the representation may be unwise; if more wisdom had been employed in the creation of the original JavaScript code I would not have set out on this adventure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to declare such in TypeScript's type system: arrays *must* have a homogenous type<sup>1</sup>

In this case the array (`Array<c'>`) is of a homogenous `c'`, where `c' = A | B`.

---

Of course, if the data-structure could be decomposed, then some additional/complex encoding might be "suitable", eg.

```
[ A, Array<B> ]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not aware of any programming language type system that allows such a restriction - for an unbound sequence - based on arbitrary pattern rules.

Comment: It's also not what arrays, lists and the like are for. If there are different kinds of elements, you probably should be using an object, giving names to the different collections.

Comment: TypeScript definitely has some support for non-homogenous types in arrays: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#333-tuple-types

Comment: @rakslice Tuples need not be homogenous. But then tuples are not arrays.

Comment: "Tuple types represent JavaScript arrays"

Comment: @rakslice TypeScript uses JavaScript as a thin compilation target; in this case that means that tuples use JavaScript arrays as the implementation. However, TypeScript types and static type verification, live *outside* of the JavaScript runtime which is otherwise 'typeless'.

Comment: Gotcha. It is compatibility with the underlying JavaScript array that I'm concerned with, I do not care if it is a TypeScript array; I have updated the question, but if TypeScript tuples and arrays are distinct types then I suspect there is no answer.

Comment: @rakslice They are distinct in TypeScript's type system. If the [external] array is not of a (small) fixed size then it does not represent a tuple and the transformation would be to a suitable `Array<c'>` - it may also be required to perform runtime logic/checks to ensure the array is 'correctly populated' per special rules.